# Move file from FtpOutBoundGateway to another remote location with dynamic filename

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-integration

I am using FtpOutBoundGateway to move one file to another remote location. As per spring documentation expression attribute is to used to supply "from" path and rename expression is used for "to" path.
I am supplying a static path and it is working fine my question is how to supply dynamic name for the rename expression?

here is my code

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    FtpOutboundGateway ftpOutboundGateway =
            new FtpOutboundGateway(sf(), "mv", "payload");
    ftpOutboundGateway.setRenameExpressionString("/processed/StaticFilename.xml");     
    ftpOutboundGateway.setOutputChannelName("results");
    return ftpOutboundGateway;
}
```

Here is messaging gateway interface :

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface Gate {    
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "ftpChannel")
    void sendToFtp(String filePath, @Header("filename") String filename);

}
```

Is there a way to set ExpressionString dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message 'payload' have the filename of the file being moved. So this does the job.

```
ftpOutboundGateway.setRenameExpressionString("'/processed/'+ payload");
```

If you wanna supply name other name original name than one can pass the value in headers and use that here.